# Inner Joining three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables I wish to inner join by a common column between them.

Say my tables are;

```
TableA TableB TableC
```

I wish to join `A-B`, but then also `B-C` all by this common field I will call common.

I have joined two tables like this;

```
dbo.tableA AS A INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS B
ON A.common = B.common
```

How do I add the third one?

Comment: dbo.tableA AS A INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS B
ON A.common = B.common inner join dbo.TableC as C on C.common=B.common

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
select *
from
    tableA a
        inner join
    tableB b
        on a.common = b.common
        inner join 
    TableC c
        on b.common = c.common
```

Comment: How would the output table would look like. Say SO questions and comments to each question, and answers to each question and comments to each answer. Three tables questions, answers, comments.

Comment: @ışık You would get all the columns from tableA, then all the columns from tableB, then all the columns from tableC. Or you can choose the columns you want

Comment: What is happening behind the second INNER JOIN; are we joining on the output which asks Is there a temporary table getting created from the first join ? If there is a temporary table then how are we calling that table.

Comment: @lft93ryt that depends on the tables, and how they are optimised. You can't refer to the "temporary table".

Answer (score 17):

Just do the same thing agin but then for TableC

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tableA A 
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB B ON A.common = B.common
INNER JOIN dbo.TableC C ON A.common = C.common
```

Answer (score 8):

```
dbo.tableA AS A INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS B
ON A.common = B.common INNER JOIN TableC C
ON B.common = C.common
```

Answer (score 7):

try the following code

```
select * from TableA A 
inner join TableB B on A.Column=B.Column 
inner join TableC C on A.Column=C.Column
```

Comment: why did you join Table C with Table A instead of Table B?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA.primary_key = TableB.foreign_key 
JOIN TableB ON TableB.foreign_key = TableC.foreign_key
```