# PostgreSQL - INNER JOIN two tables with a LIMIT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824501/inner-joining-three-tables) post which almost coincides with my question but my specific problem is that I need to put a limit to the third table/query, as in `LIMIT 15`, for example. Is there an easy way to achieve this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

My SQL SELECT statement would look something like this:

```
SELECT t2.name AS user_name, t3.name AS artist_name
FROM tbl1 t1
    INNER JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.t1able_id = t2.id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl3 WHERE artist_id = 100 limit 15) t3
        ON t2.id = t3.artist_id
WHERE t1.kind = 'kind'
```

To clarify: It's just a matter of joining two tables but the second table has two states. First state as a "common user" and the next state as an "artist" (both using the same table, e.g. `users`).

Comment: Post your SQL so we can have a look at it.

Comment: is there a primary key on table 2?

Comment: t2.id represents a common user and t2.artist_id represents the artist of a common user? there exist more than one artist for one common user?

Comment: If you want, we can use this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/517df/3) to play and you could correct me

Comment: Here's the edited [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e47a/1)

Answer (score 5):

Try this query:

```
select *
from
    tableA a
        inner join
    tableB b
        on a.common = b.common
        inner join 
    (select * from tableC order by some_column limit 15) c
        on b.common = c.common
```

Comment: When using `limit` you should also apply an `order by` otherwise the result is "random"

Comment: You can use MAX or MIN too to limit for a specific table.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized it's not using three tables but two. I have edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: @KeesSonnema As per my understanding aggregate functions like `MAX() MIN()` will return only 1 row , it is not a alternate for `limit`.. as `limit` restricts the `resultset` to specified number.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago I searched for such answer and Postgresql provides to do it smoothly with *rank()*.
My goal was to get last 3 submitted annual report files before commercial firm got started its first insolvency process.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT r.id, f.id AS id_file, f.file_date, min(p.process_started) AS "first_process_started",
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY r.id ORDER BY f.file_date DESC) AS "rank"
    FROM registry r
      INNER JOIN files f ON (r.id = f.id_registry)
      INNER JOIN processes p ON (r.id = p.id_registry)
    WHERE 
      r.type = 'LIMITED_LIABILITY_COMPANY'
      AND f.file_type = 'ANNUAL_REPORT')
      AND p.process_type = ('INSOLVENCY')
    GROUP BY r.id, f.id, f.file_date
    HAVING f.file_date <= min(p.process_started)
) AS ranked_files
WHERE rank <= 3
```