# How to use same psql subquery in from and where clause?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I want to use the same subquery in from and where clause.
Tried following two approaches, but getting same error in both cases at different places in the query.

QUERY 1:

```
select * from (subquery1) as t_feature where id = (select MAX(id) from t_feature);
```

QUERY 2:

```
select * from t_feature where id = (select MAX(id) from (subquery1) as t_feature);
```

ERROR:

`ERROR:  relation "t_feature" does not exist`

For temporary soultion, I have created a view for the subquery, and used that in place of the subquery. But I do not want to create views for this case.

Comment: maybe You should look at rank() function. I posted example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892902/postgresql-inner-join-two-tables-with-a-limit/60720220#60720220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```
with t_feature as (
   ...
) 
select * 
from t_feature 
where id = (select MAX(id) from t_feature);
```

Comment: Tried using common table expression, it worked. But not sure how `distinct` can help here. Distinct eliminated duplicate rows, but I want to pick the row with max value, and there can be multiple rows with the same MAX value.

Comment: @S.K: then I mis-understood your intentions