# Inner join (or intersect) over three tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with three tables named: `NameAddressPhone`, `NameAddressAge`, and `AgeSex`.

- Table `NameAddressPhone` has columns `name`, `address`, and `phone`.
- Table `NameAddressAge` has columns `name`, `address`, and `age`.
- Table `AgeSex` has columns `age` and `sex`.

I'm trying to write a (SQLite) query to find the names, addresses, and ages such that the names and addresses appear in both `NameAddressPhone` and `NameAddressAge`, and such that the ages appear in both `NameAddressAge`and `AgeSex`. I'm able to get halfway there (i.e., with two tables) using `inner join`, but I only dabble in SQL and would appreciate some help from an expert in getting this right. I have seen [solutions that appear to be similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11824501/959176), but don't quite follow their logic.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: Does `AgeSex` have any other columns which would specifically link an age/sex pair with a name?

Comment: ...otherwise, _anyone_ who happens to be 25 years old in `NameAddressAge` would join against the same sex in `AgeSex`.

Comment: No, no other columns (of use for that purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to join these together on their obvious keys:

```
select *
from NameAddressPhone nap join
     NameAddressAge naa
     on nap.name = naa.name and
        nap.address = naa.address join
     (select distinct age
      from AgeSex asx
     ) asx
     on asx.age = naa.age
```

This is selecting the distinct ages in the `AgeSex` to prevent the proliferation of rows.  Presumably, one age could appear multiple times in that table, which would result in duplicate rows on output.

Comment: Thanks for this, Gordon, I think this (or something like it using distinct) is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your tables have the following layout

```
NameAddressPhone
================
Name
Address
Phone

NameAddressAge
==============
Name
Address
Age

AgeSex
======
Age
Sex
```

If I am understanding everything correctly, the solution might look kind of like this:

```
SELECT P.Name, P.Address, P.Phone, A.Age, S.Sex
FROM NameAddressPhone P
INNER JOIN NameAddressAge A ON P.Name = A.Name AND P.Address = A.Address
INNER JOIN AgeSex S ON A.Age = S.Age
```

Mind you, joining AgeSex could produce duplicate rows if there are multiple rows with the same age in AgeSex.  There wouldn't be a way to distinguish 21 and Male from 21 and Female, for example.

I hope I can help and this is what you are looking for.