# php mysql 4 tables join

Tags: php, mysql, join, fetch

I have 4 tables, in table's `'tbl_Order'` has single record of each  cusotmer.
in table's `'tbl_OrderDetail'` there are more then 1 Services (records) of each customer. 
in table's  `'tbl_services'`  there are more then 10  pre-define services.
inch table's  `'tbl_users'`    there are customer's basic information.

my question is :  how I can fetch  data  by each customer using PHP with MySql. My tables details are below:

```
tbl_Order:   Order_ID,Order_Type,Order_Date,Time,Customer_ID,Booking_Type,Booking_Status,Order_No,Car_No,Booking_Date

tbl_OrderDetail: ID,Order_ID,Service_ID     

tbl_services :  Service_ID,S_Name,S_Price

tbl_users : Customer_ID ,User_Name
```

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. Please show what you've tried so far, and explain why it isn't working for you. There's nothing tricky about joining 4 tables, it's the same as joining 2 tables except you do it 2 more times.

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 0):

you can join four tables using primary key of one table with forign key of other table and at the of the query just use order by User_Name

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
    tbl_Order a
        inner join
    tbl_OrderDetail b
        on a.Order_ID = b.Order_ID
        inner join 
    tbl_services  c
        on b.Service_ID = c.Service_ID
    tbl_users  d
        on d.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
```

I would advice you to select the columns you want instead of using `*`. E.G : `a.Order_ID, b.Service_ID`

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824501/inner-joining-three-tables)